# How to disable or enable a texture (image) in Unity 2019 (in C# code)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2019. In my C# code, there are 3 simple lines as follow:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public Texture image;
image.enabled = false;
```

But, Unity 2019 says that the class Texture does not have the parameter "enabled".

This code used to work in Unity 2018. But, it fails to compile in Unity 2019.

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can enable/disable a texture. My suggestion would be changing the texture type. If you look at the texture type of that texture, it should be **Texture** by default but you can change it to **Sprite 2D**. After that, get the reference as `public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;` and then you can enable or disable it.

Comment: In Unity 2018, we can enable or disable a texture. But for Unity 2019, we can't do that. Your suggested solution is correct for Unity 2019. Thanks.